Why a standard monotone class argument proves orthogonality of Gaussian space implies independence?
The following is from J.-F. Le Gall: Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus page 8.

Theorem 1.9 Let $H$ be a centered Gaussian space and let $(H_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of linear subspaces of $H$. Then the subspaces $H_i, i \in I$ are (pairwise) orthogonal in $L^2$ if and only if the $\sigma$-fields $\sigma(H_i), i \in I$ are independent.

In the proof, it is clear why $\sigma$-fields $\sigma(H_i), i \in I$ are independent implies $H_i, i \in I$ are (pairwise) orthogonal in $L^2$. But the converse is less clear for me, and I was wondering if someone can clearify this.
I understand that to show the converse is true, it is enough to show $\sigma(H_{i_1}) \dotsc, \sigma(H_{i_p})$ are independent for distinct $i_1, \dotsc, i_p \in I$. I also understand that for each $j \in \{1, \dotsc, p\}$, if $\xi^j_1, \dotsc, \xi^j_{n_j} \in H_{i_j}$ then $(\xi^1_1, \dotsc, \xi^1_{n_1}), \dotsc, (\xi^p_1, \dotsc, \xi^p_{n_p})$ are independent.
The events of the form $\mathcal{C}_j = \{\xi^j_1 \in A_i, \dotsc, \xi^j_{n_j} \in A_{n_j}\}$ give a class that is stable under finite intersections that generates the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(H_{i_j})$. This means that the monotone class generated by $\mathcal{C}_j$, denoted as $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C}_j)$, is a monotone class and $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C}_j) = \sigma(\mathcal{C}_j)$. Now, how do we go from $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C}_j)$ is a monotone class for any $j \in \{1, \dotsc, p\}$, to $\sigma(H_{i_1}) \dotsc, \sigma(H_{i_p})$ are independent for distinct $i_1, \dotsc, i_p \in I$?

You're only missing one small technical step: if the generators $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ are stable under intersection and they are independent, then $\sigma (\mathcal{E}_1)$ and $\sigma (\mathcal{E}_2)$ are independent. A proof of this fact can be found elsewhere in MSE.

Are monotone classes equivalent to $\pi$-systems? In the link, there is no mention of monotone classes. But they certainly mention "$\cap$-stable"
